# Shared Pointer to an object in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I'm trying to figure out, what happens if you create a shared pointer, that points to an object that is held in a vector.

The Code looks like this:

```
class TestObject
{
public:
    int someTestData;
};

class Test
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<TestObject> testPointer;

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TestObject>> getTestVector()
    {
        return testVector;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TestObject>> testVector;
};
```

The Problem is, that I want to both support fast iteration over all TestObjects, but also provide shared pointers to single objects in the vector.
But now I dont know what happens if the last shared ptr to an object in the vector gets deleted.

- Does the object get removed from the vector?
- Does this cause undefined behaviour?
- How can I archieve the behaviour I want if this doesnt work?

EDIT:

To Clarify, what i need:

I need a MemoryManager Class, that has a method CreateTestObject, that creates a new TestObject, stores it in a vector or some other container that supports fast iteration and returns a some kind of shared_ptr to the newly created object so that the object that needs a new TestObject has a reference.

Now i also need the shared_ptr to the TestObject to be able to remove the TestObject from the container it is stored in, when the last shared_ptr goes out of scope, so that i'm not left with a vector full of unused TestObjects.

Comment: Are you missing a part of the code? Because your question is not completely clear to me

Comment: Please try to clarify what you actually need.

Comment: iirc shared pointer owes what it points to, do you really whant object in vector be destroyed when lifetime of pointer expire? (and then when lifetime of vector will expire it will destroy already destroyed object, ub)

Comment: How are you getting `shared_ptr<TestObject>` from objects of the `std::vector`? The objects inside `testVector` are owned by that `std::vector`. If you are creating `shared_ptr`'s with addresses to these, you are almost surely only going to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @uneven_mark i'm creating the object in the vector and then get the adress and create a shared ptr with that
Is there a way to archieve my desired behaviour though?

Comment: Why do you have a `shared_ptr<vector<T>>` ? Did you perhaps intend `vector<shared_ptr<T>` ?

Comment: This `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TestObject>> testVector;` does not match what you say you want.  It sounds like what you want is a vector of non-owning smart pointers `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<TestObject>> testVector;`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what happens on your end, since you didn't share the code which actually initializes `testPointer`. But what you're looking for is an *aliased* `std::shared_ptr`:

```
testPointer = {testVector, &(*testVector)[0]};
```

From then on, `testPointer` points to the first element of the vector, but shares the ownership of the vector itself with `testVector`, providing the correct semantics.

Do note that this *doesn't* prevent the vector from relocating its storage and making `testPointer` dangle if you cause it to reallocate.

For the record, trying to construct a `std::shared_ptr` owning the element itself, as follows:

```
testPointer.reset(&(*testVector)[0]); // Wrong!
```

... will necessarily trigger UB down the line, since `std::vector` has unique ownership of its elements already, and there's no way that you can make `std::vector` or `std::shared_ptr` relinquish ownership.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm trying to figure out, what happens if you create a shared pointer, that points to an object that is held in a vector."

That is a very bad idea because the position of any element of a vector can change simply by adding or removing an element to the vector. What you implement is simply a duplication of ownership which brakes basic OOP concepts.

> Does the object get removed from the vector?

A shared pointer is the "owner" of the object and the vector is also the owner. So it is conceptional broken!

> Does this cause undefined behaviour?

It is still undefined, as you generate dangling pointes because vector can move its objects.

> How can I achieve the behaviour I want if this doesnt work?

You have already fast access via `operator[]` and you have already "pointers" as iterators can be used as any other pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a custom deleter with your `shared_ptr` and using a container like `boost::stable_vector`:

```
testVector.emplace_back();
auto it = V.end()-1;
auto deleter = [&testVector, it] (int*) {testVector.erase(it);};
std::shared_ptr<TestObject> ptr(&testVector.back(), deleter);
```

When the last `shared_ptr` to an object goes out of scope, it will remove it from `TestVector`. Note however, that this does not work the other way round: If the object is removed from `TestVector` through any other means (e.g. by `TestVector` going out of scope), this will trigger undefined behavior, so it is your responsibility to make sure that this does not happen. Note also that this does not work with `std::vector`, as the iterators get invalidated when the vector is resized. You could however use `std::list`, although that will probably be slower than `stable_vector`.

This is not the cleanest solution (due to the very real possibility of triggering UB if you're not careful), but doing this proberly would be much more involved.